# Casting a tab in Chrome has stopped working

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, osx-mavericks, chromecast

Recently, casting a tab from Google Chrome has to my Chromecast has stopped working.  When I try I get "Unable to cast to *Chromecast Name*.  An unexpected error occurred." with the cast icon red with an X.

- Chrome can see the Chromecast.
- The Chromecast reacts when I try to cast (the screen goes blank).
- The Chromecast App can see and configure the Chromecast.
- Casting from youtube.com works.
- Casting from Youtube and Netflix apps on Android and iPads works.
- Chromecast firmware is 16041.
- There is nothing new in the console when I try to cast.

I have tried...

- Reinstalling Chrome.
- Wiping out all preferences, caches and application support.
- Disconnecting Chrome from my Google account.
- Uninstalling Chrome Remote Desktop.
- Rebooting the Chromecast.

This may have coincided with upgrading from 10.8 to 10.9.

Any more ideas of what to try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen lots of people having problems with this. First of all make sure your chrome is updated to the latest version by going into About Chrome menu option. If it is, try Google Canary. It is basically Chrome with all the new dev and aplha features, updates and bug fixes.

[Go here to Download Google Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html).

Comment: Yes, Chrome is up to date.  I gave Canary a shot and it works!  Thanks, that will work as a stop gap until they fix the stable channel.

Answer (score 1):

What's worked for me was enabling `Connect to Cast devices on all IP addresses` by typing `chrome://flags/#media-router-cast-allow-all-ips` and changing the dropdown to "Enabled".

It turns out that the router has given the TV an IP address in a different subnet and that caused Chrome to think it was outside of a private network.

Comment: I additionally had to enable chrome://flags/#cast-media-route-provider also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android TV / Google TV or whatever they call it these days :

- Reboot your TV

**Even if** it works from iOS or Android phone - this can still fix it :-)

Comment: As much as I lament describing turning a TV off and on again as "rebooting", it does often work to fix Chromecast hiccups. Sometimes I have to physically unplug the Chromecast from both the TV and its USB power. Anyhow, the original problem has long since been solved, thanks!

Comment: @Schwern I have a Sony android tv and last night I could play from my phone just fine - but no amount of restarting my PC or disabling bonjour or trying Chrome Canary would fix it. Major point being don't assume it's your PC especially if it used to work